# print lines between matching strings using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file containing following entries;

Changing to: /Out/AP/SD

```
sftp> ls -lrt

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_M.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_S.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    1724355981 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261310.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    2319514056 Oct 25 10:26 FINAL_201810261347.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 10:26 SUMMARY_201810261343.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271245_S.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271246_M.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    1725252957 Oct 26 10:17 HOLD_201810271302.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    2244889790 Oct 26 10:21 FINAL_201810271346.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 26 10:21 SUMMARY_201810271342.csv


sftp> bye
```

Changing to: /Out/AS/SD

```
sftp> ls -lrt

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    174172077 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    191231356 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_M.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    177010167 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_S.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    171490539 Oct 25 13:02 FINAL_201810261808.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 13:02 SUMMARY_201810261808.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    97238298 Oct 25 13:02 VAS_HOLD_201810261751.csv

sftp> bye

Changing to: /Out/BR/SD

sftp> ls -lrt

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 11:24 HOLD_201810261529_S.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    1721060436 Oct 25 11:25 HOLD_201810261544_M.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    1537619643 Oct 25 11:26 HOLD_201810261546.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    1545973081 Oct 25 11:28 FINAL_201810261601.csv

-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group           0 Oct 25 11:28 SUMMARY_201810261559.csv

sftp> bye
```

I want to print all lines between sftp> ls -lrt and sftp> bye which i can get using 
awk '/sftp> ls -lrt/{flag=1;next}/sftp> bye/{flag=0}flag' filename

but i want to print data as;

```
/Out/AP/SD   -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_M.csv
/Out/AP/SD   -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_S.csv
/Out/AP/SD   -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1724355981 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261310.csv
.........
/Out/AS/SD  -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 174172077 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753.csv
/Out/AS/SD  -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 191231356 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_M.csv
```

and so on...

Thank for your support...

Comment: Please do 2 essential things in your posts always. 1st- Always use CODE TAGS for samples of input and output. 2nd- Let us know what you have tried so far in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is multi line output excluding lines without a character:

```
$ awk '/^Changing to: / { match($0,/^Changing to: /); dir=substr($0,RLENGTH+1); } /^sftp> ls -lrt$/ { doprint=1; next; } /^sftp> bye$/ { doprint=0; } /.+/ { if ( doprint == 1 ) print(dir " " $0); }' sftp.out
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_M.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_S.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1724355981 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261310.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 2319514056 Oct 25 10:26 FINAL_201810261347.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:26 SUMMARY_201810261343.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271245_S.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271246_M.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1725252957 Oct 26 10:17 HOLD_201810271302.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 2244889790 Oct 26 10:21 FINAL_201810271346.csv
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:21 SUMMARY_201810271342.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 174172077 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 191231356 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_M.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 177010167 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_S.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 171490539 Oct 25 13:02 FINAL_201810261808.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 13:02 SUMMARY_201810261808.csv
/Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 97238298 Oct 25 13:02 VAS_HOLD_201810261751.csv
/Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 11:24 HOLD_201810261529_S.csv
/Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1721060436 Oct 25 11:25 HOLD_201810261544_M.csv
/Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1537619643 Oct 25 11:26 HOLD_201810261546.csv
/Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1545973081 Oct 25 11:28 FINAL_201810261601.csv
/Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 11:28 SUMMARY_201810261559.csv
```

If You need as one line output as it was in original question:

```
$ awk '/^Changing to: / { match($0,/^Changing to: /); printf("%s ",substr($0,RLENGTH+1)); } /^sftp> ls -lrt$/ { doprint=1; next; } /^sftp> bye$/ { doprint=0; } /.+/ { if (doprint == 1) printf("%s ",$0); } END { print(""); }' sftp.out
/Out/AP/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_M.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261247_S.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1724355981 Oct 25 10:24 HOLD_201810261310.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 2319514056 Oct 25 10:26 FINAL_201810261347.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 10:26 SUMMARY_201810261343.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271245_S.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:16 HOLD_201810271246_M.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1725252957 Oct 26 10:17 HOLD_201810271302.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 2244889790 Oct 26 10:21 FINAL_201810271346.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 26 10:21 SUMMARY_201810271342.csv /Out/AS/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 174172077 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 191231356 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_M.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 177010167 Oct 25 13:01 HOLD_201810261753_S.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 171490539 Oct 25 13:02 FINAL_201810261808.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 13:02 SUMMARY_201810261808.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 97238298 Oct 25 13:02 VAS_HOLD_201810261751.csv /Out/BR/SD -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 11:24 HOLD_201810261529_S.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1721060436 Oct 25 11:25 HOLD_201810261544_M.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1537619643 Oct 25 11:26 HOLD_201810261546.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 1545973081 Oct 25 11:28 FINAL_201810261601.csv -rw-rw-rw- 1 user group 0 Oct 25 11:28 SUMMARY_201810261559.csv
```

note there is added space and new line in the end

Comment: @Vikakmis: What is desired output? Could You update Question then?